# Nginx defaulting to first config for all www. requests

Tags: nginx

I host some websites with Node.js and use Nginx to make it so that I can host multiple sites on the same server. I've just started getting this problem where if, for example, I go to `examplesite1` it works fine and if I go to `www.examplesite1` it works fine aswell and if I go to `examplesite2` it works fine but when I go to `www.examplesite2` it shows the content from `examplesite1` on it. Here is the config I'm using:

`nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
}
```

`conf.d/blog.jakewalker.xyz.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name blog.jakewalker.xyz;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ghost:2368; # this is to a docker container
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

`conf.d/jakewalker.xyz.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name jakewalker.xyz;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sites:2100; # also for a docker container
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab on how to set it up.

I'm not sure if it'll help but here is my DNS for my website:

```
A        jakewalker.xyz        {ip of server}
CNAME    www.jakewalker.xyz    @
A        blog.jakewalker.xyz   {ip of server}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You do not have a server block to handle `www.jakewalker.xyz` so `nginx` will use the default server (which in your case is the first one). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for guidance.

Comment: @RichardSmith That worked great. Thanks!